# What does this mean in a storm topology "storm Insufficient Capacity on queue to emit"? And how can I increase the queue size or fix this?

Tags: apache-storm

I have a storm topology running and I get this message in debug logs for one of the bolts "storm Insufficient Capacity on queue to emit". This bolt sends message to another bolt on a particular stream. The next bolt is trying to write data to a db and hence is slower.

Does this mean that next bolt's internal queue is full and hence no more messages will be emitted? How can I increase that queue size? Also will these messages be re tried once the next bolt has processed its messages?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: It would be better to bring some code of your spout + slow bolt + topology as it will allow us to give you a pretty solution. But if it is slow: maybe you will need to "map/reduce" tuples and use a batch solution with tick tuples in your slow Bolt...